# Angular RouterOutlet rendering several components

Tags: angular, routes

`app.component.html` has the usual  in it and the Routes config is as follows:

```
const accountRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'reset-password', component: ResetPasswordComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'auth-actions', component: AuthActionsComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
];

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'account', children: accountRoutes },
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '404', component: PageNotFoundComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/404' },
];
```

What I see in the rendered page with empty url is something of the form:

```
<my-home><my-home/>
<my-login><my-login/>
```

This happens, when I route from the login page back to home page (using `this.router.navigateByUrl('');`). If I refresh the page at empty url, it shows only the homepage. Any ideas why this could be happening?

EDIT:

Wrapping the navigation `this.router.navigateByUrl('')` into `NgZone.run( <insert redirect here> )` fixes the issue. This seems to be some issue with the redirect being called in a callback outside of an ngZone. Still quite weird behaviour, as the routing service gets called, but it doesn't remove the old (login) component.

This gets called after Google Authentication window closes, so possibly this happens outside of an NgZone for some reason.

Comment: Is this happening on localhost or is it happening on a server?

Comment: Firebase hosted server

Comment: Looks like an issue with how you used <router-outlet>. Can you add all the files / code where you used <router-outlet> tag?

Comment: The only place is in the `app.component.html` and there is a single instance of it

Comment: If this happens when you call Angular code from an external library, then I doubt you can make it work without wrapping it yourself in the `NgZone`. Is that a problem ?

Comment: Not a problem, I just would like to understand when I should expect such behaviour and why is this happening in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the navigation got run outside of the `zone` for some reason. It is calling a 3rd party API (google auth), so some magic is happening inside it to leave the zone.

The solution was to wrap it in the `zone.run(/* do the redirect here */)`